# One to Nine Puzzle

Tags: mathematics

I got those from a cereal box.
You can use each number 1 to 9 only once.
Operation should match the value in the green box horizonal and vertical

[image]

[image]

My problem is Operation Order isnt specify in the instructions 
But because those puzzles are usually for childrens **my guess** is precedence is left to right and up down. 

Also for puzzle A using normal operator presedence

> first row will be 
>   9 - X*Y = 2 --> X*Y = 7 
>   and there isnt any combination using 1 to 9 to solve that. 
>   * **EDIT** * My mistake 1*7 = 7 doh

I could solve B but not A using that order.
You can show your B solution
But the correct answer go for the one finding a solution for A or proving there isnt a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR.** The first puzzle is impossible.

Looking at the first row, you incorrectly claim that there is no XY | X,Y e {1-9}
Actually there is.  1 and 7.

BUT

Given the left column, the only possible solution is 9 x 7 - 5 = 58, which means there can't be a 7 in the first ROW.

Proof: 9 x 6 = 54, and we can't subtract to get 58.  9 x 8 = 72, and we need to subtract 14 to get 58

So, we must assume that the operator precedence is left to right.

This makes the first row 9 - 7 x 1 = 2, which runs afoul of our first column.,
or 9-8 x2 = 2, Which frees up the seven for the first column,  but kills us in the second column, where 8 - X + Y = 8, which implies X = Y, which is impossible.

Comment: Beaten by 17 seconds. Damn :D

Comment: Nice to see someone else come to the same conclusion.

Comment: You are right didnt saw the 1*7 :$

Answer (score 7):

Assuming left to right precedence, in the third row we should have 1 in the third column, So:

```
9 -   *   = 2
*   -   *
  +   *   = 39
-   +   +
  -   * 1 = 1
=   =   =
58  8   7
```

Then we have 2 for the last column of first row, and the middle one would get the value of 8:

```
9 - 8 * 2 = 2
*   -   *
  +   *   = 39
-   +   +
  -   * 1 = 1
=   =   =
58  8   7
```

Next step follows:

```
9 - 8 * 2 = 2
*   -   *
  +   * 3 = 39
-   +   +
  -   * 1 = 1
=   =   =
58  8   7
```

Now, in the first column, the only possible values are 7 and 5:

```
9 - 8 * 2 = 2
*   -   *
7 +   * 3 = 39
-   +   +
5 -   * 1 = 1
=   =   =
58  8   7
```

Then:

```
9 - 8 * 2 = 2
*   -   *
7 +   * 3 = 39
-   +   +
5 - 4 * 1 = 1
=   =   =
58  8   7
```

The remaining cell should be 6. This works for the row, but then the column's result would be 6, not 8. I guess this is a typo.

Solution for B:

```
9 + 7 + 3 = 19
*   *   *
6 - 2 + 4 = 8
+   -   *
1 * 8 - 5 = 3
=   =   =
55  6   60
```

Comment: +1 for a good explanation (simple typo 6->8) of how an unsolvable puzzle would end up on a cereal box.

Comment: +1 Yes, i also tought was a typo too. But want to give you guys a try :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think **A** is solvable at all, no matter the order of operations.

- First row: `9-a*b=2`

For any order of operations, the only options for *a* and *b* are 7 and 1. If you tried using left-to-right order and `9-8*2`, then you run into a problem in the middle column where you have `8-c+d=8`, which needs a repeated number.

- First column: `9*e-f=58`

Since 58 is not a multiple of 9, the order of operation can only be multiplication first. So now we need a multiple of 9 that is *more* than 58, but *less* than 68 (since you can only subtract a single digit number to get to 58). The only one is 63, which is `9*7`. However, 7 is already taken (first row) and can't be used again.